# Proper Route for multiple providers - Symfony2 Security

Tags: symfony

I am creating a security with multiple providers.One providers for sonata admin and another provider for custom frontend user

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
    database_users:
        entity: { class: MyBundle:Users, property: username }
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    admin:
        pattern:            /admin(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /admin/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
        anonymous:          true
    main:
        pattern:      .*
        form-login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
    secured_area://created for custom frontend user
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            provider:  database_users
            check_path: /security/login_check
            login_path: /security/login
            #csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: voters_list
            always_use_default_target_path: true

        logout:
            path: logout
            target: homepage
access_control:
    # The WDT has to be allowed to anonymous users to avoid requiring the login with the AJAX request
    - { path: ^/wdt/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # AsseticBundle paths used when using the controller for assets
    - { path: ^/js/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/css/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # for the case of a failed login
    - { path: ^/user/new$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/check-confirmation-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/confirm/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/confirmed$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/request-reset-password$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/send-resetting-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/check-resetting-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/reset-password/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Admin login page needs to be accessed without credential
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Secured part of the site
    # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
    # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    SONATA:
        #- ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

acl:
    connection: default
```

I have no problem with the sonata admin which is provided by the FOSUserBundle, but the custom frontend user throw error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "security/login_check" as such route does not exists

Inside my app/routing.yml, I imported the routing created for the custom frontend user

```
Custom_security:
resource: "@MyBundleBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.yml"
prefix:  /security
```

And inside the MyBundle routing

```
login_check:
path:   /login_check
#defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Security:loginCheck }

logout:
    path:  /logout

login_user:
    path:   /login
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Security:login }
```

I am confused why Symfony throws the exception error, I imported the MyBundle routes in config/routing.yml
And my login form looks like this

```
<form action="{{ path('security/login_check') }}" name="form" id="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
         <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus/>                    
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
           <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>
    </div>                                                                  
    <div class="form-group">
       <!-- Button -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
        <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-log-in"></i> Log in</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

update

I change my form into

```
   <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" name="form" id="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
         <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus/>                    
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
           <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>
    </div>                                                                  
    <div class="form-group">
       <!-- Button -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
        <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-log-in"></i> Log in</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And also the routing inside MyBundle

```
  login_check:
    path:   /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Security:loginCheck }

  logout:
    path:  /logout

  login_user:
    path:   /login
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Security:login }
```

And created a method for testing inside MyBundle

```
  public function loginCheckAction()
  {
       throw new \Exception('This should never be reached!);
  }
```

And the error

> This should never be reached!

Try to remove default controller for the login_check

```
login_check:
path:   /login_check
#defaults: { _controller: DuterteBundle:Security:loginCheck } //removed
```

Throws the error

> Unable to find the controller for path "/security/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 {{ path('security/login_check') }}
```

in

```
{{ path('login_check') }}
```

also your Yaml file is not correct. change it in:

```
Custom_security:
    resource: "@MyBundleBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.yml"
    prefix:  /security
```

And inside the MyBundle routing

```
login_check:
    path:   /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Security:loginCheck }

logout:
    path:  /logout

login_user:
    path:   /login
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Security:login }
```

Comment: I think there is no need to manually add a controller for login_check route since Symfony will automatically handle it.Anyway I tried to use your example and added some method for the loginCheckAction inside the Security controller.....public function loginCheckAction() { throw new \Exception('This should never reached!'); and indeed throws that error.